# file_put_conents знаки вопросика

Tags: php

Появилась проблема с кодировкой или, черт его пойми, с чем.

Вот код:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$user = $_GET['nick'];
$settings = $_GET['settin'];
$tes = str_replace("\q", "\n", $settings);
file_put_contents($user.'.ini', $tes);
?>
```

Он получает информацию на кириллице и создает файл, в echo все нормально, но вот в самом ini файле, который он создает, появляются знаки вопроса.

Что делать? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file_put_contents` бинарно безопасен. Это означает, что в файл будет записано в точности то что сказано.

Соответственно, вопросы к той программе, которой вы затем пытаетесь читать этот файл. У кириллицы куча разных кодировок и отображать данные из файла необходимо строго в той кодировке, в которой данные были записано.